# A group with bounded element orders and its minimal and maximal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

Let $n>1$ be an integer. Is there an abelian group $G$ with all elements of order less than $n$ for which exactly one of these conditions is correct:

1) every non-trivial subgroup of $G$ contains a minimal (non-trivial) subgroup of $G$.

2) every proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal (proper) subgroup of $G$.

?

How if abelianness is omitted?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I need a hint for an example!

Comment: Sorry - I should clarify. It's helpful for you to share your thoughts so far on the problem. This helps people who want to answer tailor their answers for you. For example, if I were to look at this problem, I'd jump straight away to the structure theorem for finite abelian groups - but I don't know if you've studied that yet!

Comment: I need a hint; no matter elementary or advanced or a reference to a paper!

Comment: Think about the structure theorem for finite abelian groups :)

Comment: every finite abelian group satisfies both the conditions. But I want exactly one condition be satisfied. So the example must be an infinite group.

Comment: Every torsion group satisfies 1).

Comment: @DerekHolt: So it remains (2). btw, it's hard to restate the quedtion if I remove (1) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every abelian group of bounded exponent satisfies (1) and (2).

As I pointed out in my comment, every torsion group satisfies (1), because every nontrivial subgroup contains a cylic group of prime order, which is clearly minimal.

So let $G$ be an abelian group of exponent $n$. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup. Then there exists $g \in G \setminus H$, and by a standard application of Zorn's Lemma, we can find a subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $H \le N$ and $N$ maximal subject to $g \not\in N$.

So, in the quotient group $G/N$, $xN$ is contained in every nontrivial subgroup. A finitely generated abelian group with that property must be cyclic, so $G/N$ is locally cyclic, and hence all finitely generated subgroups of $G/N$ are cyclic of order at most $n$. But that implies immediately that $G/N$ itself is cyclic of order at most $n$, so it has a maximal subgroup and hence (2) holds.

I don't know whether (2) holds for all groups of exponent $n$ if you drop the abelian condition - I would guess not, but I don't knoe an example.

Comment: It seems to work for nonabelain case if *subgroup* is replaced by *normal subgroup*.